# Adding multiple "temporary" values in a datagridview and store them in the database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, temporary

Hello is there somebody here who knows how to add temporary datas into a datagridview?

I have 2 comboboxes: genderComboBox(Items: Female, Male), countryComboBox(Items: USA, Germany)
1 button (buttonAdd):
1 datagridview (genderColumn, countryColumn):

How can I add them to the datagridview?  I don't want them to store directly to the database.

And How can I add multiple values of them in the gridview?

Here's what I tried

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
            table.Columns.Add("Country");
            table.Rows.Add(countryComboBox.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
```

In this solution I can see 2 problems:

1. Everytime I click the button it always creates a new column. What I want is that I will just specify what column and fill it with datas.
2. Every time I click the button it doesn't add what I've added before. Therefore I can't add temporary multiple values in the datagrid.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list item that is a datamember of the class that contains the OnClick event. Set the DataSource to the list in the constructor. When someone clicks the 'add' button, add an anoymous object to the list using the values from the comobo boxes, then rebind the data to the datagrid. Here is a brief example.

```
YourClass
{
private List<object> list;

public Page_Load(object sender, args e)
{
          if (!isPostBack) // only initialize once when the page first loads
          {
              list = new List<object>();
              datagrid.datasource = list;
          }
}

protected void OnClickButton(object sender, args e)
{
     list.add(new { Gender = genderComboBox.Text, Country = countryComoBox.Text });
     datagrid.DataBind();
}
}
```

Edit:
Here's a link for more info on anonymous types, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx . For me they are much more flexible and dynamic for quickly populating a grid than manually creating columns, etc.

I re-wrote my example a bit after reading one of your comments to better solve your specific problem.

Comment: Thank You very Much Sir! I have a question sir, Which approach is better? putting it in a datatable or in a generic list?

Comment: It's personal preference which method you use. I'm always more comfortable with the OOP approach. To me it feels more natural to just have a list of objects, then those objects have properties rather than have grids and columns. On the other hand if you work more with Relation Database Systems you may very well prefer the datatable approach. Use whatever feels most comfortable to you (unless your boss tells you otherwise, then I would listen to him).

Comment: sir does this mean that I should have an add method in my object class?

Comment: I really want to try this approach. Can you please explain what does list.add() do?

Comment: list.Add() adds the newly created anonymous object to the in-memory list member. This is what keeps track of all the past items you have added so your grid does not reset each time. The list is your actual storage container for the objects, and the datagrid is just used to display the contents of the container.

Comment: sir why I am only able to add 1 record?

Comment: it is probably creating a new list on each postback. To fix this, replace the code that is in YourClass() constructor inside the pageLoad, but check for postback so it only initializes it once.

Answer (score 1):

1. Thats because you create a Column on each click.
2. Thats because you create a DataTable on each click.

Put the creation code in the constructor, then the add method in the click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

the result is a new clear Datatable. Thats the reason why your old insert is missing
Do it like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //insert your value at the right place
           datatable.rows.add();
           datatable.rows[datagrid.rows.count].cells[x].value = countrybox.Text;
           //x = columns index of your country column
        }
```

create your columns at startup, maybe form_load

```
datatable.columns.add("country");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
//Create 2 datasource for combobox in grid
                DataTable genderTable= new DataTable();
                genderTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(int)));
                genderTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String)));
                genderTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, 'male'});
                genderTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 'female'});

                DataTable countryTable= new DataTable();
                countryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(int)));
                countryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String)));
                countryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, 'USA'});
                countryTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 'Germany'});

//Create 2 combobox column
                 DataGridViewColumn gender= new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewComboBoxCell());
                 DataGridViewColumn country= new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewComboBoxCell());

//Add column into grid
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(gender);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(country);
// Add rows into grid, number of rows is 10 
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]).DataSource = genderTable;
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]).DisplayMember = "Name";
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]).ValueMember = "Value";
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]).Value = 0;

                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]).DataSource = countryTable;
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]).DisplayMember = "Name";
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]).ValueMember = "Value";
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]).Value = 0;
         }
```

HTH.

Comment: Why is the number of rows set sir? And Why is there a datagriviewComboboxCell? I've already added the combobox and the datagrid in the designer why would I manually create it sir?

Comment: Number of rows should be based on your demand.
If you've already created combobox, just remove the line adding these columns into datagrid.

Comment: sir what I'm trying to do is to add multiple temp data in a datagridview. It's not adding batch files into the grid. What I meant is to add 1 data then add another and all of it will be stored in a datagrid. for ex: *select gender in combobox, click add, show 1 record in datagrid. then select gender, click add, show 2 records in datagrid

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand, I supposed that you need a datagrid having combobox columns, and add rows dynamically.

Comment: it's ok. Sorry too, for not explaining my problem well. xD